# 하지만 이겨내야 해 and 하지만 이겨내고야 difference

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, difference

In the Dungeon Fighter Soundtrack I recently listened to both by Dazbee and Hyukso Kwon, I notice that they use different word choices.

While Hyukso Kwon used `하지만 이겨내야 해`, Dazbee used `하지만 이겨내고야`.

Is it because the different use by gender or is there any other reason?

Comment: 오우! [kyuksoo kwon has a fantastic voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaIdZXAq5EY&vl=ko)!

Comment: Can you add more of the two phrases so there is a bit more context?  I've tried finding the reference online, but I've not had any luck, so my answer is left guessing at the missing pieces.  Add those so that I can update my answer to be more exacting.

Answer (score 3):

There is no gender role in Korean language. It is just a difference of diction.

Roughly translating into English, "하지만 이겨내야 해" is "But I have to overcome it." and "하지만 **이겨낼거야**"(There was a misspelling in your sentence.) is "But I will overcome it."

Both sentences are expressing the will to overcome an obstacle or defeat his/her enemy.

Answer (score 2):

My wife, a native speaker, was pretty sure that the second one is `하지만 이겨낼 거야` meaning `and yet (subject) is likely to win`.  It is possible that she and jungyh0218 are correct.

Also, jungyh0218 is correct - there is no inflection or grammar for gender, only for age and position.

Still, `아/어 겠다` is "will" and `ㄹ/을 거다` is "will likely", so it seems incorrect to say that each person is responding with a "will win" since `이겨낼거야` is a weakened statement where the person is leaving that room for the chance of loss.  This would have not been said with great force, for that would make them look weak, not strong.

**IMPORTANT CONTENT**

My wife and I continued to disagree on this, as I kept feeling like `고야` had a place in this sentence.  Again, we really need more context.  It is also possible that there is more to the sentence that Dazbee is saying.

I found two references to support this theory (since we certainly can't leave Dazbee as a weakling unsure of what he's saying, eh?):

*외국어고서의 한국어문법사전, 백봉자 지음 ISBN 89-7699-437-X 03710 2006-03-22 1쇄 발행, page 102b-103a:* indicates that `-고야` is a 연결어미 (conjunction).  It gives the following examples (among others):

- 아기는 우유 한 병을 **마시고야** 잠이 들었어요 (the baby **has to drink milk** to go to sleep)
- 잘 도착했다는 **전화를 받고야** 안심을 했어요 (i have to **get the call** that you're safe in order to feel comforted)

We already know that since `하지만` tells us something is left off the beginning of the sample phrases/sentences that it's also possible this is being used as a "must" conjunctive to more that is apparently left off the end.

**2ND IMPORTANT CONTENT**

I found [a link that suggests that in early modern korean there is an exclamatory that would sound like `고야` but is actually `괴야` (look at the latter portion of page 280)](https://www.scribd.com/document/351783039/Ki-Moon-Lee-S-Robert-Ramsey-A-History-of-the-Korean-Language-pdf).

If this is what is being said, then the comparison would show that Dazbee is using a slighly more archaic (and therefore more powerful imho) exclamatory saying *whoever the subject is...dazbee probably?* is going to win (with some old school power to boot)!

Here is the excerpt:

[image]

**CONCLUSION**
We have to leave it to the OP, since we don't have access to the media in question.  I will cast my vote for the comparison to be between:

> -이겨내야 해
>
> -이겨내 괴야!

which would then allow us to say:

> These two phrases do not have any gender difference, only a semantic/grammatical choice that leaves Dazbee saying **the win is assured** in an *exclamatory and archaic/rough tone* while Hyukso Kwon is just pointing out that **winning is a must**.

Comment: Not sure this really answers OP's question. She was looking for an explanation of the difference, not a translation.

Answer (score 0):

both answers seem correct. To add a bit more, 이겨내야 해 has more emphasis on the necessity of overcoming something - "it HAS to be overcome" - whereas 이겨낼거야 emphasizes the hope of overcoming it - "it WILL be overcome".